# Adding multiple Recycling.LogEventOnRecycle events programmatically

Tags: c#, .net

I have:

```
    ApplicationPool BOB = iisManager.ApplicationPools.Add("BOB");
    BOB.Recycling.LogEventOnRecycle = RecyclingLogEventOnRecycle.OnDemand;
    BOB.Recycling.LogEventOnRecycle = RecyclingLogEventOnRecycle.IsapiUnhealthy;
```

The issue that I'm having is that I don't know how to assign multiple attributes to the LogEventOnRecycle event. Any help would be appreciated a lot.... been going around with this for ages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN, [LogEventOnRecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpoolrecycling.logeventonrecycle%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is of type [RecyclingLogEventOnRecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.recyclinglogeventonrecycle%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?), which is an `enum` that "has a `FlagsAttribute` attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values."

Thus, something along these lines should work for you:

```
    RecyclingLogEventOnRecycle myRecycleEvents = 
        RecyclingLogEventOnRecycle.OnDemand | RecyclingLogEventOnRecycle.IsapiUnhealthy;
    ApplicationPool BOB = iisManager.ApplicationPools.Add("BOB");
    BOB.Recycling.LogEventOnRecycle = myRecycleEvents;
```

Note that you need to use the logical bitwise OR operator `|` rather than the addition operator `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+=` instat of `=` as it will add and not overwrite something.

Comment: @Stelly could you post the declaration of `LogEventOnRecycle` please?